# Accessing JSON objects in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to read in a JSON, filter it based on certain properties, and then add the objects that fit the criteria into a format that I can use in other functions.

Here's what it looks like so far: `

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {"X-API-Key": "My_API_Key"}
        }).done(NJ_filter);

filtered_data = [];

function NJ_filter( data ) {
    $.each( data.results[0].members, function( i, item ) {
        if (data.results[0].members[i].state == "NJ") {
            filtered_data.push(data.results[0].members[i]);
        };
    });`
```

It appears to return an array of objects, indexed by float. But when I try to access any of the objects by `console.log(filtered_data[0])`, I get back an undefined. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the connection between JSON and arrays, but I can't pinpoint what I'm doing wrong. Anyone have guidance on how I can better input this JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably call JSON.parse() to the response of the AJAX in order to parse it to a JS object.

Comment: I get this message: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: You could simply call console.log() and then log the response of the AJAX. Can you please provide me with this info?

Comment: Which I tested with `function NJ_filter( data ) {
 parsed = JSON.parse(data);
 console.log(parsed)
 // JSON.parse(data);
 // console.log(data);
 $.each( data.results[0].members, function( i, item ) {
  if (data.results[0].members[i].state == "NJ") {
   NJ_congress.push(data.results[0].members[i]);
   // console.log(data.results[0].members[i]);
  };
 });`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, but the idea is that I parsed the results of the ajax call and put them in a variable called parsed.

Comment: This is the first couple lines: 
{
   "status":"OK",
   "copyright":" Copyright (c) 2017 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.",
   "results":[
      {
         "congress": "114",
         "chamber": "House",
         
         
         "num_results": "448",
         "offset": "0",
         "members": [
              {
                 "id": "A000055",
             ....
                 ,"missed_votes_pct": "1.66",
                 "votes_with_party_pct": "94.40"
               },
                           {
                 "id": "A000367",

Comment: The results of console.log(filtered_data): Array[0]
0
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
Object
8
:
Object
9
:
Object
10
:
Object
11
:
Object

Comment: Then each object looks like: Array[0]
0
:
Object
api_uri
:
"https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/F000372.json"
district
:
"11"
...
votes_with_party_pct
:
"92.91"